# How to run tests showing code coverage in Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.3.4

Tags: development, visual-studio-code

I'm new in C# after a brief use of it in 2010.

I'm asking an Internet search engine - one claiming not to track me - how to "visual studio for mac show tests coverage".

That would link me to [Use code coverage to determine how much code is being tested](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019).

I think that's no use to me, because they command to:

> 1. On the **Test** menu, select **Analyze Code Coverage for All Tests**.

I don't have such a menu to begin with.

This is Visual Studio for Mac Community 8.3.4.

How to?

Comment: Due to lack of on topicness there's a lack of useful answers. Cross posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58602334/ and hit a close vote here. Your close votes here are welcome. Cheers.

Comment: There is an answer below. If it doesn't help you and you want to have the question moved to another site, please flag for mod attention. Migrating questions is better than cross-posting as migrating keeps comments and answers intact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow VS release cycles, but

> A fix for this issue has been released! Install the most recent release from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Thank you for providing valuable feedback which has helped improve the product.

<sup>from 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/623728/vs-2019-test-explorer-menu-disappeared-from-the-pr.html</sup>

And

> Edit: Found the culprit, it was Microsoft Intune Endpoint Protection that was installed on my pc. It basically scanned everything and when visual studio got updated and files were written to the disk, something went wrong and corrupted my install. I turned it off by excluding C:* from being scanned and ran VS2013.5 update and clicked repair. Everything is fine now.

<sup>From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604119/visual-studio-test-missing-from-the-main-menu</sup>

Comment: Unbelievable!!!